# Python 2.7 IDLE giving an error on mac

Tags: macos, python-2.7, python-idle, activetcl

I am having a problem with my python 2.7 IDLE, (and the other parts, but mainly this.) Whenever I open it, it displays this error.

[image]

I have tried installing a new version of ActiveTcl, but it still won't work. Is there a special way I have to configure it?

System Specifications - Mac Mini OS X version 10.8.5 2.3 GHz Intel Coee i5 4 GB 1333 MHz DDR3

Comment: The IDLE opens a sub-process to execute the code in. The connection to this process is made via sockets. The IDLE can not connect to this process. You can either enable the connection or tell idle not to use any sub-process. Thi has nothing to do with Tkinter.

Comment: i am guessing IDLE (or a specific module of it) requests internet connection. try adding it to your firewall permit access list, as the message says and see what happens. But i am only guessing since i  am not using MAC and this message is error is surely  weird.

Comment: How do I enable connection/tell it not to use subprocesses?